# Where does Craft store the field definitions?

Tags: templating, fieldtypes

I would like to add field and section definitions to versioning. Or at least, have them backed up constantly.

I haven't been able to find out yet how craft handles this. I'd say it's in the database, but apparently it's not: the database has a `uid` column where values like `305ed8b6-3519-422f-8436-eca448145656` are stored. This probably refers to some git-ish entries in the file system.

So is this out of reach for manual save/restore/export/import?

Answer (score 2):

Basically look for the tables "craft_fields", "craft_content" and "craft_sections".
For Fields you can use the "Field Manager" Plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with Field Manager! I just realized that it doesn't (of course) save entry types & sections. This is stuff that IMHO should be in versioning. Is there another way to export that too?

Comment: The Plugin "Feed Me" is available for Craft 2 + 3. That can import/export entries (free version) an Categories, Users, and Commerce Products (Pro only).

Comment: But this exports content, right? I only want to version the settings/structure for fields, sections and entry types

Comment: Ok, i just learned, "Feed Me" can only import Entries from CSV, JSON etc.. You may have a look at "Architect" https://github.com/Pennebaker/craft-architect

Comment: Yay, that looks more like it!!